# Сообщение с условием Да и Нет

Tags: html, jquery

Необходимо при нажатии на кнопку чтобы выходило сообщение - Обращение в отношении Заявителя или другого лица если type= Жалоба.

Необходимо чтобы еще и спрашивало Да и Нет. 
Если нажимаем Да – то все срабатывает и ничего не требует,

если нажимаем Нет – то требует ввести данные в поле surname_pred  и  name_pred(если точнее варианты ввода surname_pred, name_pred, surname_pred && name_pred).

После того когда в поле(я) введены данные то дальше пускает. 
Как можно убрать в выпадающем окне слова – Подтвердите действие на странице localhost:6065 и убрать кнопки ОК и Отмена. Вместо них прикрутить Да и Нет.
Приготовленные css файл(пока пустой)

Как можно сделать окно по красивее, тем самым оформив стили в файле style3.css и как эти стили применить к части моей функции?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/style3.css"/>" type="text/css"/>
```

Html

```
<select id="type" name="typeId" onchange="document.getElementById('typeWarning').hidden = true;"><option value="0"></option><option value="1">Жалоба</option>…
…
<input id="surname_pred" name="surname_pred" type="text" value="">
<input id="name_pred" name="name_pred" type="text" value="">
…
```

Часть функции

```
 else if($('#type').val() == 1){
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 else if($('#type').val() == 1 && $('#name_pred').val() == 0){
     strMessage = (typeof strMessage !== 'undefined') ? strMessage : 'Обращение в отношении заявителя?'; 
     return !!confirm( strMessage );         
    }
```

Comment: Пока использую такой ответ, если кто знает лучше, подскажите

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать confirm(), он возвращает true или false, в зависимости от того какую кнопку нажали. То есть как то так

```
if(confirm('Обращение в отношении Заявителя или другого лица')){
  //все срабатывает и ничего не требует
}else{
   //требует ввести данные в поле surname_pred и name_pred
}
```

Но здесь тоже будут кнопки ок и отмена.

Comment: Интересует тот же вопрос. Как написать аналог confirm?