# Оформить сообщение и убрать лишнее

Tags: jquery

Как чтобы сообщение выходило по середине, вместо ОК и Отмена чтобы было Да и Нет, также применить к сообщению стили прямо в этой функции(шрифт по жирнее, окно по красивее ) ну и убрать фразу – Подтвердите действие на странице localhost:…

```
 else if($('#type').val() == 1 && $('#name_pred').val() == 0){
     strMessage = (typeof strMessage !== 'undefined') ? strMessage : 'Обращение в отношении заявителя?'; 
     return !!confirm( strMessage );         
    }
```

Comment: Написать свой алерт или использовать сторонние, например `bootstrap`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сообщение с условием Да и Нет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/926380/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%94%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%9d%d0%b5%d1%82)

Comment: Вопрос состоит в том - как оформить и убрать лишнее в выпадающем сообщении.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896777/how-to-remove-close-button-on-the-jquery-ui-dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартный confirm кастомизировать нельзя. Но есть несколько вариантов что можно сделать.

1. Воспользоваться готовым решением, например, [JQuery UI dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

```js
$(function() {
  $('.openModal').on('click', function () {
    $('#dialog-confirm').dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height: 'auto',
      width: 400,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        'Да': function() {
          $(this).dialog('close');
          // сделать что-то если да
        },
        'Нет': function() {
          $(this).dialog('close');
          // сделать что-то если нет
        }
      }
    });
  });
 });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Обращение в отношении заявителя?">
</div>

<button type="button" class="ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget openModal">Открыть модальное окно</button>
```

2. Написать свое модальное окно

```js
$(function () {
  $('.openModal').on('click', function () {
    $('.modalDialog').show();
  });
  $('.close').on('click', function() {
    $('.modalDialog').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.modalDialog {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity: 1;
  display: none;
}

.modalDialog > div {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}

.close {
  background: #606061;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -10px;
  width: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }

button {
  color: #fff; 
  user-select: none;
  background: #D44B38;
  padding: .7em 1.5em;
  outline: none;
}
button:hover { background: #E85F4C; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="openModal">Открыть модальное окно</button>

<div class="modalDialog">
  <div>
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
      <h2>Обращение в отношении заявителя?</h2>
      <button>Да</button>   
      <button>Нет</button>   
   </div>
</div>
```